# Excel - Count number of occurrences of number string with Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've looked around here, and other online sources but can't seem to find the solution to what I'm after.

I have a data table with 78,000 rows. The table is set up as follows:

```
A               B          C   
Issue           Client ID  Ticket Number  
Printer Jam     123456     HP-123  
Monitor         987654     HP-124  
Keyboard        123456     HP-125  
Printer Jam     123456     HP-126  
Keyboard        987654     HP-127  
Printer Jam     987654     HP-128
```

This goes on and on. I need to count the number of times a **Client ID** appears for each **Issue**, so that I can report the number of repeat "offenders" on it like this:

```
Issue         1   2   2+  
Keyboard      2   0   0  
Printer Jam   1   2   0
```

Hopefully that makes sense! I've tried using a Pivot Table, and while it gives me the counts I need it doesn't really do what I need.

Thanks!

Comment: What is it exactly that the pivot table doesn't achieve?

Comment: I don't understand how you reached your count. What do the columns represent?

Comment: You could also use CountIfs()

Comment: @Jerry, I imagine the columns are classifications on how many times the issue was raised by a single user. So there are two people that reported a printer jam twice.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use `COUNTIFS` together with a pivot table if I had to do this:

[image]

`COUNTIFS` will be moderately slow due to the size of your data, but the pivot table will make the grouping part relatively fast.

From the picture, I am using this for the `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right that the `COUNTIFS` is taking some time, but it seems to be working... i'll just be patient and watch the % counter go up by 1% at a time :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,$E2,$B$2:$B$7,$B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7,$A$2:$A$7)=1))
```

Change the `=1` to `=2` and `>2` for the next columns.

[image]

Comment: Haven't got this to work yet, but I think it may be because of the # of rows of data (78,000)... Excel looks like it's working on calculating, but doesn't display the "Calculating" % counter on the bottom. I'm going to try leaving this sitting all day tomorrow and see what happens.

Comment: With that amount of data you will want VBA.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses two `PivotTables` and one `Range`.

It assumes the `DATA` range is located at `B6:D111111`

1. Add a `PivotTable` *(PtCount)*, with the `DATA` range as source and starting at `G6`, to obtain the *Issue* \ *Client Id* counts. *(see Fig. 1 below)*

   Fig. 1
   [image: fig. 1]

   Change the settings of the `PivotField` *"Issue"*, by right clicking the `PivotField` then click on `Field Settings…` \ tab `Layout & Print` \ `Repeat item labels` *(see Fig. 2 below)*

   Fig. 2
   [image]
2. Use a `Range`, located at `L6` and parallel to the `PivotTable` *(PtCount)*, to manipulate the `PivotTable` results (i.e. change counts higher than 2 to *"2+"*. *(see fig. 3)*

   The range should have these items\formulas:

   **Issue** : `=T($G7)`

   **Count** : `=IF(EXACT($L7,""),"",$I7)`

   **Offenders** : `=IF(EXACT($L7,""),"",IF($I7>2,"2+",$I7))`

   Fig. 3
   [image]
3. Add a second `PivotTable` *(PtSummary)*, with the `Range` starting at `L6` as source and located at `G6`, to generate the final report. *(see fig. 4)*

   Fig. 4
   [image]